# Resets for OpenTelemetry counter metrics

Tags: open-telemetry

I can't see support for this, but I'm wondering how, if you have a cumulative counter metric, you compute deltas without having support for resets?

For instance, if my process has count over time of [12, 13, 17, 6, 8] - then I want the delta result to be [1, 4, **6**, 2] not [1, 4, **-11**, 2] - based on the assumption that any drop is the result of reset to 0.

Even better, would be support for explicit resets, i.e. recording a '0' point, so that if it went [3, 4, 5, RESET, 6] the output would be [1, 1, 6] not [1, 1, 1].

Are folks solving this some other way?

Thanks!